# LAMP Server Image CD

Tags: lamp

I have very limited unix skills, so I say I am a rookie.

I want to setup a LAMP server. Is there a cd image i can download that will install all of the LAMP components?

This will host an eCommerce site with small amount of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ubuntu Server image. From the [list of packages provided](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.list), Apache, mysql, php and well, Linux are all included. (The list isn't in alphabetic order, so you might have to jump around a bit if you search within a browser.) When installing using the server edition, you'll be shown a "Software selection" screen which asks for tasks to install, and you can choose `LAMP server` from the list.

[image]

Download the Server image of your choice from http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/.